# Vector comparison out of range

Tags: c++, vector, 2d, curses

I'm making a simple game and I'm having trouble creating boundaries for the players movements. The map is a 2D vector. When I compare the vector with the players current position I get an error during run. The error tells me that the vector is out of range.

Here is the where the map is created. It's within its own class constructor.

```
vector< vector<char> > map_parts;
map_parts.resize(25);
for ( int i = 0; i < 25; i++ )
{
    map_parts[i].resize(80);
}

//check if file open worked
ifstream map_reader ( "C:/Users/Ryan Melendez/Desktop/C++/programs/Curses/City.txt" );
if ( ! map_reader )
{
    printw( "Error.\n" );
}

//save map to memory
while ( ! map_reader.eof() )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < 25; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < 80; j++ )
        {
            map_reader >> noskipws >> map_parts[i][j];
        }
    }
}
map_reader.close();

//print map
for ( int i = 0; i < 25; i++ )
{
    for ( int j = 0; j < 80; j++ )
    {
        printw( "%c", map_parts[i][j] );
    }
}
```

And here is where the vector is being compared to determine whether or not the player is colliding with a wall. This code is written as a method within a different class. The first case has a simple IF test to see if the coordinate to the left is a wall.

```
//Move player
void player_class::movePlayer()
{
    int temp = getch();
    switch (temp)
    {
        case KEY_LEFT:
            if (map_parts[player.x - 1][player.y] == '|' || '_')
            {
                break;
            }
            move(player.y, player.x);
            addch(' ');
            player.x--;
            break;
        case KEY_UP:
            move(player.y, player.x);
            addch(' ');
            player.y--;
            break;
        case KEY_RIGHT:
            move(player.y, player.x);
            addch(' ');
            player.x++;
            break;
        case KEY_DOWN:
            move(player.y, player.x);
            addch(' ');
            player.y++;
            break;
    }
    move(player.y, player.x);
    addch(player_char);
}
```

Comment: `if (map_parts[player.x - 1][player.y] == '|' || '_')` is always true.
and there's no limit for `player.x` and `player.y` for all cases of keys.